Using async CompletableFuture<Dto> always returns 403
I'm using a controller where I have to upload large files, the problem is when return CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ExecutionDto>> it always returns error 403, but when I change the return type it returns the DTO successfully but it's blocking. The authentication is working fine. What could be the issue?
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ExecutionDto>> handleFileUpload(
        @RequestPart("file1") MultipartFile file1,
        @RequestPart(value = "file2", required = false) MultipartFile file2) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    List<MultipartFile> files = new ArrayList<>();
    files.add(file1);
    if (file2 != null && !file2.isEmpty()) {
        files.add(file2);
    }

    User user = userRepository.findByEmailWithAgency(userService.getAuthenticatedUser().getEmail()).get();

    String uploadId = "upload_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Upload ID : " + uploadId);
    progressTracker.initializeProgress(uploadId);

    return executionService.handleFileUpload(files, uploadId, user)
            .thenApply(ResponseEntity::ok);
}

I tried adding the security context on the service, but still nothing.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that the security context is propagated to the threads executing your CompletableFuture. There are a few ways to do this:

Use @Async with Security Context Propagation.
If your application uses Spring's @Async for asynchronous processing, you can use the @Async annotation in combination with the SecurityContextHolder strategy configuration.
Manually Propagate Security Context in CompletableFuture.
Alternatively, you can manually propagate the security context when using CompletableFuture.

